# How to estimate the gradient of an argmin function.

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks

Suppose we have a family of functions $\{f_{\theta}(x)\}_{\theta}$ parameterized by $\theta$.

Now, let $x^*(\theta):=\arg\min_x f_\theta(x)$ be the minimum point for $f_\theta$.

Suppose the function $x^*(\theta)$ is differentiable (reminded by David), my question is: how to estimate the gradient $\frac{d x^*(\theta)}{d \theta}$ ?

I did some surveys and found this gradient (in fact any gradient) can be estimated by the [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) technique. However, it is rather slow when $\theta$ includes many parameters, *e.g.*, $f_\theta$ is a neural network.

Any possible approach is welcomed.

---

Update: supplement some details for Hyperplane's answer, in case anyone else is interested in this question.

- IFT (Implicit Function Theorem): [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Earchristian/teaching/32a-f16/implicit-function-theorem.pdf) and [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20189/notes/Chapter3/S3.1.html).
- Regularity conditions under which $x^*(\theta)$ is differentiable: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261172/interchange-derivative-and-argmin) and Corollary. 2 in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.06809.pdf).
- The Hessian vector product trick: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725697/matrix-vector-product-vs-matrix-computation). Why this trick is helpful for iterative solvers: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368475/how-the-hessian-matrix-is-used-in-optimization-if-you-cant-invert-it).
- Common methods to solve a linear equation (system): [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/how-to-choose-a-method-for-solving-linear-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- Use LU decomposition to solve a linear equation [here](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/cs357/sp2020/notes/ref-9-linsys.html#:%7E:text=Solving%20LU%20decomposition%20linear%20systems&text=In%20equations%20this%20is%3A,1%20b%20).
- Details for iterative methods, e.g. CG, MINRS, and GMRES: [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eholee/math361-2020/lectures/Conjugate_gradients.pdf) and [here](https://netlib.org/templates/templates.pdf)

Comment: Without any additional assumption on the structure of the family of functions $\{ f_\theta(x)\}_\theta$ the function $x^* : \theta \mapsto \arg \min_x f_\theta(x)$ is not necessarily differentiable (or even continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done via the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). Given suitable regularity conditions, assume $x^*(\theta)$ minimizes $f(x, \theta)$. Then

$$\begin{aligned}
    0 &= \frac{∂f(x^*(\theta), \theta)}{∂x}
\\ ⟹ 0 &= \frac{}{\theta}\frac{∂f(x^*(\theta), \theta)}{∂x}
\\ ⟹ 0 &= \frac{∂}{∂x}\frac{f(x^*(\theta), \theta)}{\theta}
\\      &= \frac{∂}{∂x}\Big(\frac{∂f}{∂x}\frac{x^*}{\theta} + \frac{∂f}{∂\theta}\frac{\theta}{\theta}\Big)
\\ ⟹ &\;\boxed{\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}\frac{x^*}{\theta}=-\frac{∂^2f}{∂x∂\theta}}
\end{aligned}$$

This linear equation can be solved with iterative techniques without ever computing the full Hessian $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}$ explicitly, by making use of Hessian Vector Products: $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}v = \frac{∂}{∂x}\Big(\frac{∂f}{∂x}v\Big)$ and an iterative solver like GMRES.

See for instance:

- [Optimizing Millions of Hyperparameters by Implicit Differentiation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.02590)
- [Deep Equilibrium Models](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/hash/01386bd6d8e091c2ab4c7c7de644d37b-Abstract.html)
- http://implicit-layers-tutorial.org/